# Overlaying Plots With Two Different Y-axes Using ggplot2

Tags: r

I am trying to combine two different plots (one a box plot and one a line plot) that have the same x axis (date in years (yr)) but different y axes (box plot is fork length (fl) and the line plot is harvest (har)). These data are in to different data frames. A simple version of the code I am using is:

```
p1 <- ggplot(biojay, aes(yr, fl))+
geom_boxplot(colour="black", fill="dark gray")+  
theme_bw()+   
theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(300,900), breaks=breaks1)+       
xlab("Year")+                                              
ylab("Fork Length (mm)")+                                  
theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14))+      
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12))+     
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) 

p2 <-  ggplot(har, aes(yr2, harjay))+
geom_line(linetype = "solid", color="red", size=1.25)+
theme_bw()+  
theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())+ 
scale_y_continuous(position="right") +
xlab("Year")+                                        
ylab("Harvest (kg)")+
theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14))+       
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12))+       
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

I have tried to combine these using multiple methods I have found online, but nothing seems to work for me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are plenty of similar posts on this...is it that you need a primary and a secondary axes?

Comment: Thank you. I have been searching for days and still can't get this to work. I would two primary y axes showing different variables (length (fl) on one and harvest (harjay) on the other). The x axis is year. I am not sure if this issue is that these data are in two different data frames, but I am stalled.

Answer (score 0):

```
p1 = qplot(1:10,1)
p2 = qplot(1:10,1:10) + theme_minimal() 

print(p1)
print(p2, newpage=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. This almost works, but the second plot does not line up at all with the first one. I am guessing it is because I am pulling in data form two different data frames?